# Can't submit my extension to the Chrome Web Store: "An error occurred: Invalid manifest."

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to submit a Google Chrome extension to Chrome Web Store, but I get the following error:

> An error occurred: Invalid manifest. If your manifest includes comments, please remove them as our gallery does not support them yet.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "IMGit Image Uploader",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "Easy and fast image uploading from a simple right click.",
    "background": {"page": "imgit.html"},
    "icons": {
        "16": "16.png",
        "48": "48.png",
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["contextMenus","tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*",],
    "manifest_version": 2,
}
```

Adobe Dreamweaver shows a syntax error on line 2. No idea why.

What's wrong?

Comment: Use jslint.com, it will tell you your JSON errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting rid of *both* extra commas you have in your JSON:

```
{
"name": "IMGit Image Uploader",
"version": "1",
"description": "Easy and fast image uploading from a simple right click.",
"background": {
    "page": "imgit.html"
},
"icons": {
    "16": "16.png",
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

You can validate your JSON files [here](http://jsonlint.com/).